# Specialize a template class with a member function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

I'm working with VS 2008 (sorry, can't update). I need template specialization for my list class. The argument I want to specialize is a member function pointer.

In short, how can I make the following code work (I can' use variadic templates):

```
// two or three args
template <typename T1, typename T2, void (T1::* FUNC)(const T2&) = 0> struct list;
// specialized code for 2 args.
template <typename T1, typename T2> struct list<T1, T2> { };
```

The error message is:

> C2754: 'specialization' : a partial specialization cannot have a dependent non-type template parameter

Maybe there is no solution for my problem. But that also an answer.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: This might be one of those instances where you would use a delegate. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/213x8e7w%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: why do you need that specialization? the primary template has a default argument, meaning you can omit it. what would you like to achieve?

Comment: If the member function pointer is null I have to implement a complete different list class. And would like to separate these two implementation to have clean code (no if ... else).

Comment: @Tebc I don't want to mix it with c# because the code needs to run under linux as well and should be native c++. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I do understand correctly what you are trying to achieve, **it cannot be done**. Let's consider an even *simpler case of **illegal** specialization*:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, void (T1::* FUNC)(const T2&)> struct list;
template <typename T1, typename T2> struct list<T1, T2, 0> { };
```

Here you always have to supply three arguments to instantiate your template, and you try to specialize the primary template for the case where the last argument is a null pointer.

Per **§ 14.5.5/8** of the C++ Standard:

*"The type of a template parameter corresponding to a specialized non-type argument shall not be dependent on a parameter of the specialization. [ Example:*

```
template <class T, T t> struct C {};
template <class T> struct C<T, 1>; // error

template< int X, int (*array_ptr)[X] > class A {};
int array[5];
template< int X > class A<X,&array> { }; // error
```

*—end example ]*"

You cannot specialize a non-type argument whose type is dependent on other types in the template parameter list. Thus, the above specialization is illegal.

Your original design is just a *particular case* of this specialization, where the last (non-type) parameter has a default argument value, which you omit in the specialization (omitting it is legitimate *per se*). The reason why this is illegal is **not** related with the presence of a default argument, but rather with the fact that you are trying to specialize a **non-type** argument that **has a dependent type**.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! That makes sense to me. Now I have to search for another solution for my problem.